# Binding application.properties to a class from external library in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's say I have an external jar (that supposed to work in spring boot env) that has this simple class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
public class NetworkConfig {
  //getters/setters
...
}
```

Now I use this jar as dep in a Spring project (**NOT Spring Boot!!**).

I have an application.properties file in that project and want to load properties from it to this class and it should be available in a context. How would I do it?

I also need to mention that external jar is my lib and I can modify it if needed.

Comment: If the class is already annotated as configuration properties, all you need is `@EnableConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar well the point is that parent project is Spring and not spring boot as mentioned: `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is a part of spring boot.

Answer (score -1):

@ConfigurationPropertiesScan ("path_to_property")